# Adding property to nested objects in Flow causes errors

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I can add a property to a flat object in Flow without any errors.

**[View demo](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDCcAdhnmWALxgDeqYjYAzjAK4DmAXCxgE4BLEhwA0DMAEgMAjDDw9m-IaNQBfANzps+Im0VwAtsTIUM1IqXKUAZHVQSAFngCGAEzx8Akgecd5vQWExDXQoNhIAY2lSMFc4AGVDPAwHZQB1GQdjKwwACgjLUx5s0wBKOyYwPmS2PhIwAG17CQKTMgA6Vk4xCRbCjulZPDFKgF1NVVDwqIEYuMSDZNThDJTCPQxDErJ8-oxija298vpK6oxa+qbe1pzO9hUbvfbBuRHKplvTdqc3D29fMNxIxxmp0KhWoowBFDkY9gd9HC2mYaKcWA8eAByYDkRSY96vfyYgAqeDx71+7i8Pj8WOAAgMHHaACscBx8WpNKh5kkUulMts8jDEYLSpoeYs+SsBbDBflZcdNEA)**

But if I add a property to a *nested* object using the same pattern, Flow throws an error:

```
/* @flow */

type Content = {
    fields: {
        slug: string,
    },
    frontmatter: {
        title: string,
    }   
};

type CustomContent = {
    fields: {
      slug: string,
    },
    frontmatter: {
        title: string,
        // This is the new property:
        headerImage: string,
    }
};

function doSomethingWithContent(content: Content) {
    return [
        content.fields.slug,
        content.frontmatter.title,
    ];
}

function doSomethingWithCustomContent(content: CustomContent) {
    return [
        content.fields.slug,
        content.frontmatter.title,
        content.frontmatter.headerImage,
    ];
}
```

Error:

```
doSomethingWithContent(customContent);
                           ^ Cannot call `doSomethingWithContent` with `customContent` bound to `content` because property `headerImage` is missing in object type [1] but exists in object type [2] in property `frontmatter`.
```

**[View demo](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDCcAdhnmWALxgDeqYYAkFAJZ4wAmAzgFx0NGQptxgBXAOb9uGAE6sSEgDSDGAXxWMWs0hgC2AQwzlZ-elqYZWGGHmlyFy1EzVNUagNzps+ImJlwesRkFBjUAlpsHDxmqkKikvbyippCGoLauobGeKYRQlpWNnZgMslOBVoAFngGnLkAkoYSJWWOqeruXqhQYiQAxlakYJxwAMqBeBhVjgDq1lXB5GQAFP26ofxLoQCU+YyyU2KyJGAA2s5M6yFkAHRRXNy3CU5MVxt3UDpk2Sa3RbYOmAALpeNToXoDIanUYTPRTGaKebTQj+DCBbara7LDBbNEYj4YPbmISHDDHU4XN7Y0L3diPZ7iV7vG4Ye7ffRGP4AvAqamE9lZLm5W41OqNZq8uKg9zoa4yMD9fFBQl4gIq1nhEkPGL7UpM-gAcmA5BkhtS6UYXyFOTyJMYPKNABU8GagWL6rImgYWkbgKw9BJbgArHASc2CcGedCwybTOYLTEYNbKpM7Lyx+HxpGJ1OElPqtNeIA)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, the `frontmatter` property needs to be marked as [covariant](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/), e.g.

```
type Content = {
    fields: {
        slug: string,
    },
    frontmatter: {
        title: string,
    }   
};
```

to

```
type Content = {
    fields: {
        slug: string,
    },
    +frontmatter: { // Note the "+" prefix here
        title: string,
    }   
};
```

If Flow *didn't* error on this, it would be perfectly valid for your function to do

```
function doSomethingWithContent(content: Content) {
  content.frontmatter = { title: "" };
```

which make the type of `content` still a valid `Content`, but an invalid `CustomContent` object. By marking the property covariant, it essentially makes the `frontmatter` property read-only.

Comment: The [covariant documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/) doesn't mention the `+` syntax, so I am a little confused.

Comment: Fair, maybe it's on another page somewhere. It's certainly here: https://flow.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance/#property-variance

Comment: Did that fix your issue though?